# How to uninstall pip packages on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

How to uninstall pip packages on Elastic Beanstalk?

We removed a package in our requirements.txt file, but we think the package is still there because its causing a namespace collision with another app we created with the exact same name.

details:

We used to have this package django-whatever. In our .py files, it was imported like

```
from whatever import something
```

the package wasn't giving us enough control, so we rolled out our own package called whatever

which we use like

```
from whatever import goodstuff
```

AWS EB now returns an error "cannot import goodstuff from whatever" which heavily implies that django-whatever is still installed even tho its not in requirements.txt

Answer (score 1):

So far, I think the best option is to ssh into the instance and do something like:

```
source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && yes | pip uninstall package-to-uninstall
```

You can alternatively add the following as a container_command in your syspackages.config file in .ebextensions :

```
command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && yes | pip uninstall package-to-uninstall"
```

Please, let me know if you figured out a more elegant way to fix this.

Comment: You saved my life. Thanks.
I used just "command: yes | pip uninstall package-to-uninstall". There is no need to load the environment while you are deploying the application.

Comment: I got permission denied with first command. And if I use sudo it cannot find the package

Comment: Got it, had to switch to root using `sudo su` than the command worked