# pip force reinstall in requirements.txt

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, pip, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a requirements.txt file in which I have some git+ references. I would like to always reinstall these as for some reason, even if I make changes and bump the version and push it to my github repo, pip says requirements already satisfied and doesn't install.

Here is part of my requirements.txt file:-

```
Django==1.10
git+https://github.com/myaccount/myrepo.git@master#egg=some_egg
```

I don't want to reinstall everything in the requirements.txt file. Only the git+ requirements.

I tried this:-

```
git+https://github.com/myaccount/myrepo.git@master#egg=some_egg --install-option="--upgrade --ignore-installed --force-reinstall"
```

But none of the above options worked.

Comment: The easiest way to do this would just be to run `pip install --upgrade -r requirements.txt`. This will reinstall the git dependencies.

Comment: Ok. But I am using AWS Elasticbeanstalk and am unable to find a way to override the pip install command execution. Any ideas?

Comment: You can uninstall those packages first. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42299244/2011147)

Answer (score 1):

Pip developers stated [in 2017](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/17#issuecomment-289058617) that they don't want you to be able to force reinstall in requirements.txt, although I don't think they explained why.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you haven't adviced `pip` what version do you have in git:

```
git+https://github.com/myaccount/myrepo.git@master#egg=some_egg
```

For VCS URLs `pip` doesn't look into the repo to find out the version, it only look at the URL:

```
git+https://github.com/myaccount/myrepo.git@master#egg=some_egg-version
```

example:

```
git+https://github.com/myaccount/myrepo.git@master#egg=package-1.0.8
```

When you push a new version to Github update your `requirements.txt` with new version(s) and run `pip install -r requirements.txt -U`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably one option is to install the package in editable mode, like

```
Django==1.10
-e git+https://github.com/myaccount/myrepo.git@master#egg=some_egg
```

Answer (score -1):

I use this:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

And you can use some thing more like :

```
pip install -r requirements.txt --no-index --find-links
```

`--no-index` - Ignore package index (only looking at --find-links URLs instead).

`-f`, `--find-links <URL>` - If a URL or path to an html file, then parse for links to archives